# What is the correct implementation for a deduplicator with a weak hash map?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I found the notion of "deduplicators" at Aleksey Shipilev's slides "The String catechism" (https://shipilev.net/talks/joker-Oct2014-string-catechism.pdf , slides 49 ff). Many Java programmers know the similar concept of interning from String.intern().
However, deduplicators are a potential memory leak if no weak references are used.
I wonder how a correct implementation for a deduplicator with a weak hash map must look like. I tend to option B but I am not sure.

Option A: 
Using a WeakHashMap is enough. The "weak key" ensures that objects are removed when they are not used anymore.

Sample implementation:

```
public class SimpleWeakHashMapDeduplicator {
    private final WeakHashMap<Object, Object> weakHashMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public Object deduplicate(Object potentialDuplicate) {
        if(potentialDuplicate == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return weakHashMap.computeIfAbsent(potentialDuplicate, (key)->key);
        }
    }
}
```

Option B:
Using a WeakHashMap is NOT enough. All values must be WeakReferences because the instance of ComplicatedWeakHashMapDeduplicator strongly references the weak hash map which strongly references the array with the entries where one entry strongly references the value. Only the key is weakly referenced by the map. Where am I wrong?

Sample implementation:

```
public class ComplicatedWeakHashMapDeduplicator {
    private final WeakHashMap<Object, WeakReference<Object>> weakHashMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public Object deduplicate(Object potentialDuplicate) {
        if(potentialDuplicate == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return weakHashMap.computeIfAbsent(potentialDuplicate, WeakReference::new).get();
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: WeakReference based string cache is impractical. It consumes too much memory. WeakReferences may significantly impacting GC time.

Comment: See [Guava WeakInterner](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html#newWeakInterner()).

Comment: Such a map has the potential to consume far more memory than the few duplicate objects.

Comment: I have not known the Guava WeakInterner. Thanks maaartinus. I will try it out.

Comment: WeakReferences might be expensive and cause longer GCs but I do not see an alternative to avoid duplicates without creating a potential memory leak.

Comment: That depends on the application. E.g., we have an application that imports a large data set at some times and simply uses a `HashMap<Object,Object>` (or `HashMap<String,String>` specifically) to deduplicate values encountered during the import, but drops that map afterwards. This doesn’t avoid duplicates at all costs, but has a reasonable saving without the overhead of the `WeakHashMap` that consumes memory by itself. But consider using a recent JVM and builtin [`StringDeduplication`](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/g1:-from-garbage-collector-to-waste-management-consultant) first.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with "Option B", but you're not quite there yet.  This line is problematic:

```
return weakHashMap.computeIfAbsent(potentialDuplicate, WeakReference::new).get();
```

Let's assume for a moment that the weak map contains a previously cached value.  You call `computeIfAbsent` and get a *weak* reference back.  Nothing prevents the garbage collector from reclaiming its referent during the brief window before you `get()` it.  If that happens, you end up returning `null`.

Your logic needs to be a bit more robust.  Try something like this:

```
public final class WeakCache<T> {
    private final WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>> _map = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public synchronized T cache(final T value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final WeakReference<T> oldReference = _map.get(value);

        if (oldReference != null) {
            final T oldValue = oldReference.get();

            if (oldValue != null) {
                return oldValue;
            }
        }

        _map.put(value, new WeakReference<>(value));

        return value;
    }
}
```

This will prevent your cached values from leaking, but it's worth asking just how eager you want to be when releasing old values.  If your values tend to be short-lived but are expected to pop up again and again, you may want to hold on to them longer.  In that case, you might consider using `SoftReference` as a value wrapper instead.  Soft references behave similarly, but they tend to hold on to their referents until faced with memory pressure.  Oracle's 'server' VM (the default for x64) will prefer to expand the heap rather than release soft references, so your application's memory usage may hit its limit sooner, at which point it will start evicting unreachable values.  It's a trade-off, and neither is a 'one size fits all' solution.  A flexible implementation might abstract the reference creation into a pluggable policy, making it trivial to choose between weak and soft references when you first create the cache.

Comment: Your solution solves some flaws of my solution for option B

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked the following comment in the javadoc of WeakHashMap:

> Implementation note: The value objects in a WeakHashMap are held by
>   ordinary strong references. Thus care should be taken to ensure that
>   value objects do not strongly refer to their own keys, either directly
>   or indirectly, since that will prevent the keys from being discarded.
>   Note that a value object may refer indirectly to its key via the
>   WeakHashMap itself; that is, a value object may strongly refer to some
>   other key object whose associated value object, in turn, strongly
>   refers to the key of the first value object. If the values in the map
>   do not rely on the map holding strong references to them, one way to
>   deal with this is to wrap values themselves within WeakReferences
>   before inserting, as in: m.put(key, new WeakReference(value)), and
>   then unwrapping upon each get.